# Creating page templates in Wordpress 5.0

Tags: wordpress

I wondered why in page attributes there is no templates dropdown anymore? 
Is there another way how templates should be made now?

Do i need to make page-{slug}.php now or is there another way, because it was easy to use templates for multilingual pages, just add template once and select it on every page language. Now i would need to make a .php file for each language because of the slug.

[image]

There is no templates dropdown

[image]
Previously there was

Comment: can you share your code for template?

Answer (score 1):

The page attributes dropdown is still there, though slightly hidden.

Look for the top right cog icon: **Settings => Document => Page Attributes**.

Comment: There is no templated dropdown, i updated my question with images

Comment: Are you sure your in the page admin and not in the post? Your screenshot has excerpt and discussion which is normally for posts.

Answer (score -1):

Ok i found a problem. Theme was broken because my style.css file was deleted out of nowhere. That was the problem. When i added style.css back, then all templates showed.